# Airflow triggering dag failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, airflow, pymysql, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am trying to trigger a dag manually from within my python code as follows:

```
from airflow_local.operators.mmttrigger_dagrun_operator import \
MMTTriggerDagRunOperator

# in loop
MMTTriggerDagRunOperator(
            task_id='trigger_dagrun',
            execution_date=datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'),
            python_callable=trigger_dag,
            trigger_dag_id=log_fetch).execute(kwargs)

time.sleep(1)
```

This code is placed in finite loop.
I am aware that the execution date for each dag run must bbe unique for the same dag trigger attempt, which explains the `time.sleep(1)`
Yet, after running through the loop, some dags are triggered successfully, and the loop stops with an error attempting to insert a duplicate entry into dag_stats table in airflow database

> Error:
>   (pymysql.err.IntegrityError) (1062, "Duplicate entry 'log_fetch-running' for key 'PRIMARY'") [SQL: 'INSERT INTO dag_stats (dag_id, state, count, dirty) VALUES (%(dag_id)s, %(state)s, %(count)s, %(dirty)s)'] [parameters: {'dag_id': log_fetch', 'state': 'running', 'count': 0, 'dirty': 1}]

I cannot understand this behavior, so if someone can help me figure out the reason behind this error, I would appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your code is wrongly formatted since the sleep function is on the very left. Also, if this is not the case please add the whole code since I am unclear what you are doing exactly. I also cannot see a loop.

Comment: Please check log_fetch-running id is duplicated, Please share your full code.